# If function is increasing is the Taylor approximation increasing?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Assume I have a function $f(x)$ that is strictly increasing for all $x$. Can one prove that the Taylor approximation is also increasing?

The condition I get is that if $x>x^{\prime}$. Then the approximation for x is larger than the approximation $x^{\prime}$ if

$$ f^{\prime}(x_{0})+f^{\prime \prime}(x_{0})\left[ (x+x^{\prime}) -2x_{0} \right] >0  $$

Since $(x+x^{\prime}) -2x_{0} \approx 0$ then the result seems to hold. But can one make a better argument without invoking the fact that $x$ and $x^{\prime}$ are close to $x_{0}$.

Comment: If you are approximating $f$ with an even-degree polynomial, won't it be decreasing on some part of the domain?

Comment: Try a function whose first derivative is always positive, but whose second derivative may be negative.  Something like $sgn(x)\sqrt{|x|}$, with the second order approximation.

Comment: Ok, so I can only make this statement locally assuming the second derivative is finite as well.